# using nested forms with has_many through - can't assign mass attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, has-many-through

I have read pretty much every question here about the nested forms with has_many through associations, but I can't get my model to work. Can someone please help?

There are 2 models: archetypes and skirtpreferences, linked through a skirtpreferencing model.

Here are the models:

> class Archetype < ActiveRecord::Base   attr_accessible :occasion,
>   :skirt_partworth, :title, :skirtpreferencings_attributes
>
> has_many :skirtpreferencings   has_many :SkirtPreferences, :through
>   => :skirtpreferencings   accepts_nested_attributes_for :SkirtPreferences   accepts_nested_attributes_for :skirtpreferencings
>   end
>
> Blockquote
>
> class Skirtpreferencing < ActiveRecord::Base   attr_accessible
>   :archetype_id, :skirt_preference_id, :skirtpreferencing_attributes
>
> belongs_to :archetype   belongs_to :SkirtPreferences
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :SkirtPreferences
>
> end
>
> class SkirtPreference < ActiveRecord::Base   attr_accessible
>   :archetype_id, ....
>
> has_many :skirtpreferencings   has_many :archetypes, :through =>
>   :skirtpreferencings
>
> end

The form looks like this and that is displaying just fine:

> <%= form_for(@archetype) do |f| %>   ...   
>       <%= f.fields_for :skirtpreferencing do |preference_builder| %>
>         <%= preference_builder.fields_for :SkirtPreferences do |builder| %>
>       <%= render "skirt_preferences_field", :f => builder %>
>       <% end %>    <% end %> ...

I imagine I hav to do something in the controllers, but I am not sure exactly what.

Thanks!

Adding the Controllers:

```
class ArchetypesController < ApplicationController

 def new
 @archetype = Archetype.new
 @archetype.skirtpreferencings.build
end

    # GET /archetypes/1/edit
def edit
  @archetype = Archetype.find(params[:id])
end

 def create
 @archetype = Archetype.new(params[:archetype])     
end 


class SkirtPreferencesController < ApplicationController   

 def new
 @skirt_preference = SkirtPreference.new
 end 

 def edit
 @skirt_preference = SkirtPreference.find(params[:id])
 end


 def create
 @skirt_preference = SkirtPreference.new(params[:skirt_preference])

 end
```

Comment: Is the form generated for the `new` method in ArchetypesController?

Comment: Please cut down your code to the problem section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing this is many-to-many relationship between SkirtPreference and Archetype, while SkirtPreferencing is the association between SkirtPreference and Archetype?

Try changing from `skirtpreferencing_attributes` to `skirtpreferences_attributes`. That's my hunch. Because you are trying to add data to skritpreferences, not the skirtpreferencings which are just there to associate between skirtpreferences and archetypes.

I also think this is unusual.

`has_many :SkirtPreference, :through => :skirtpreferencings`

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :SkirtPreference`

...

`belongs_to :SkirtPreference`

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :SkirtPreference`

All these normally should be `:skirtpreferences`.

---

** EDIT 1 **

Assuming the forms are generated in new action in ArchetypesController...

You seem to be missing the part where you build a skirtpreferencing attribute out of archetype.

So in your new action in ArchetypesController

```rb
def new
  @archetype = Archetype.new
  @archetype.skirtpreferencings.build
  ...
end
```

** Edit 2 **

`SkirtPreferences` should be changed to `skirtpreferences` except for class name.

Can you try changing `f.fields_for :skirtpreferencing do` to `f.fields_for :skirtpreferencings do`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. Made the changes you suggested - same message. But to your first question: yes, many-to-many between SkirtPreference and Archetype, through skirtpreferencing.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error message? I want to find out which attribute is causing the error.

Comment: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: skirtpreferencing

Comment: Try changing `<%= f.fields_for :skirtpreferencing do |preference_builder| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :skirtpreferencings do |preference_builder| %>`. With `s`

Comment: I take what I said earlier back. Change `skirtpreferences_attributes` to `skirtpreferencings_attributes` in Archetype model

Comment: Then I have a different problem: the portion of the form for skirtpreferences will not show up.

Comment: Can you share how the controller method looks like for the view?

Comment: So, yes, the form is rendered for "new". I tried what you suggested with the build action, but I still get: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: skirtpreferencing

Comment: Did you change `:skirtpreferencing_attributes` to `skirtpreferencings_attributes` ?

Comment: Yes - I made all of the changes you suggested. This is really boggling my mind.

Comment: It's a quirky problem. Can you update the question code to the latest changes? I will be back later tonight to look at this question again.

Comment: Based on edit 2 - changed the instances of SkirtPreference to skirtpreference. When I change f.fields_for :skirtpreferencing do to f.fields_for :skirtpreferencings do then the form will not render the portions related to skirtpreferences.

Comment: I realized what happened when I was trying to do something else. When I generated the scaffold for SkirtPreference I used skirt_preference instead of SkirtPreference. It seems I have confused myself and ruby in the process. I am going to revert back to a previous version and start these models over.